# Count acf repeater with radio value only

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm wondering if its possible to get the count of a ACF repeater field only if its got a certain radio value ?

Currently Im using

```
$status = count( get_sub_field('sub_property_status') );
```

In my template file to get the number of repeated rows in my custom post. Works fine.

But in that custom post theres a radio button option with either "Draft Sub-Listing" or "Published Sub-Listing" to hide or show a curtain repeater row.

Ideally I'd like to be able to count the rows that have the "Published Sub-Listing" only.

Is this possible ?